# aws summarize returning different sizes based on human-readable parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am running

```
aws s3 ls --recursive --summarize --human-readable s3://{blahblah}/novaseq/CLI022222/
```

This gives me a total size for this directory of 960.6 GiB

However, if I run this command without the --human-readable param, this is the result I get.

```
aws s3 ls --recursive --summarize s3://praxisgenomics-project-prod/novaseq/CLI022222/
```

Total size 1031411373687... which is ~1031 GB...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, turns out:

GiB != GB

GiB == 1024^3
GB == 1000^3

1031411373687/(1024^3)=960.58

I didn't realize GiB != GB.

Answer (score 1):

Like **Fidi Naj** said one GB is defined as 1000³ (1,000,000,000) bytes and one GiB as 1024³ (1,073,741,824) bytes. That means one GB equals 0.93 GiB.